# Why doesn't $.when.apply work as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery

So say I had an array of $.post functions

```
var pa = [$.post(url0), $.post(url1),......];

$.when(pa[0],pa[1],...]) // works as expected
```

but

```
$.when.apply(pa) // does not work
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Function.prototype.apply` requires the *context* as first argument (the object which serves as reference for `this`, in the called function)

So you can call it like

```
$.when.apply( null, pa );
```

I like to use a little "trickery" to avoid that every time. We can invoke `Function.prototype.bind` like

```
var when = Function.prototype.apply.bind( jQuery.when, null );
```

now, we indeed can call

```
when( pa ).done( /* ... */ ) { }
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use:

```
$.when.apply($, pa);
```

The first argument of `apply` is the context in which the function should be invoked (i.e. what `this` means in the context of the function). The second argument is an array with the arguments of the function.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot the first argument to [`.apply()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply), which is the thisArg of the function. Since [`$.when`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/) does not care about its value of `this`, you can pass anything:

```
$.when.apply(null, pa);
$.when.apply($, pa);
```